# JavaScript does not work on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add a JavaScript snippet on a page.

HTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<script charset="windows-1251" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ozon.ru/PartnerTwinerNew.aspx?revident=af76eb4c-d6c7-4708-807b-664db33ecae1" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you open that page and look at the source code and then click the "src" link, it shows this:

```
document.write(" <link rel=\"Stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"//www.ozon.ru/styles/charger/style.css\" /> <link rel=\"Stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"//www.ozon.ru/styles/charger/00.css\" />  ............... ")
```

Comment: Why are you using `document.write`? You should really add style sheets to the head

Comment: Error messages? Check your console

Comment: That javascript is pregenerated and I use it as is that is why there is document.write if I understood correctly.

Comment: The script has the `Content-Type` set to `text/html`, and no `.js` extension. This could confuse your browser.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It shouldn't. But then again, I have no idea what browser OP is using.

Comment: Try adding the following in your code that is outputting the script: `response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/javascript");`

Comment: @Juan Mendes, console shows nothing. I use firebug.

Comment: @Andy Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine as this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9ou0ycud/) shows.

I put the code snippet

```
<script charset="windows-1251" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ozon.ru/PartnerTwinerNew.aspx?revident=af76eb4c-d6c7-4708-807b-664db33ecae1" ></script>
```

In the html box and it outputs the following:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ozone.ru](http://static2.ozone.ru/multimedia/books_covers/l60/c120/1004121257.jpg))</sub>

And so on.

If you're not sure what's happening then it's always useful to check the console in the developer tools.

Note that with html5 you can replace this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

with this

```
<!doctype html>
```